# Hashing decompressed and compressed files with 7zip sdk - c#

Tags: c#, sdk, sha256, 7zip, lzma

I am using the 7z SDK to compress and decompress files.
I want to read the file before compressing it, generate a sha256 hash, write on the file and compress it.

When decompressing, I will read the hash, store it in a variable, decompress the file and get a new hash to compare with the hash stored in the variable to check the integrity of the file.

When compressing the file I included this block:

```
            //Write the hash size from the original file
            int HashCodeSize = Hash.generateSHA256Hash(input).Length;
            byte[] hashSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(HashCodeSize);
            output.Write(hashSize, 0, hashSize.Length);

            //Write the hash from the original file
            byte[] fileHashCode = new byte[8];
            fileHashCode = Hash.generateSHA256Hash(input);
            output.Write(fileHashCode, 0, fileHashCode.Length);
```

When decompressing the file I do this:

```
            //read the hash size from the original file
            byte[] hashSize = new byte[4];
            input.Read(hashSize, 0, 4);
            int sizeOfHash = BitConverter.ToInt16(hashSize, 0);

            //Read Hash
            byte[] fileHash = new byte[sizeOfHash];
            input.Read(fileHash, 0, 8);
```

When I include those two blocks, I get an *unhandled exception from the SDK,
without them blocks the program works perfectly.

That is how I am generating the Hash:

```
public static byte[] generateSHA256Hash(Stream fileSource)
{
    SHA256 fileHashed = SHA256Managed.Create();
    return fileHashed.ComputeHash(fileSource);
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image: unhandled execption]

Comment: `I get an unhandled exception` please add the message and stacktrace

Comment: You probably need to set stream position to the beginning of the file after you write. Try to add `output.Position = 0;` after write. Or you using different streams for writing and compressing?

Comment: I am using different streams. I have two methods to compress and decompress the file.

Comment: hmm it's hard to imagine what are you actually doing in your code. I am only guessing you know. From the code in screen I would say you have corrupted compressed file header. I would triple check and make sure you are using correct stream you writing to. By the way you calling generateSHA256Hash twice.

Comment: It could be. If I delete the hash block it works. The error is somewhere there, I guess. I just cant see what it is

Comment: Can you post simple example of your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the pointer to the begining of the file before writing it solved my problem:

```
 input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```